# Electric field exerted by a ball with varying density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

Say there's a ball with radius R. In $0<r<d$, the density is some $\rho_1(r)$ and in $d<r<R$, the density is $\rho_2(r)$. When I calculate the total charge enclosed in $d<r<R$, how should I treat the $\rho_1(r)$ density in the $0<r<d$ part? It doesn't make any sense to keep it varied with radial distance when I calculate the electric field outside the range in which the density formula is applicable. Should I integrate or is there some other way of treating it?

Comment: Have you considered using [Gauss' Law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)?

Comment: I'm using it, I was just wondering what would Q be when I'm outside the range.

Comment: Since there is no charge outside $r=R$, so the $Q$ will be the same value everywhere that is, the charge of the whole region from $r=0$ to $r=R$.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should integrate it !

But you already know the result, it is the total charge of the inner ball
$$
Q_1= \iiint_{r<d}\!\!\rho_1(r)\mbox{d}V
=4\pi\int_0^d\!\! \rho_1(r)r^2\mbox{d}r
$$

And its contribution to the electric field is proportional to $Q_1/r^2$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having a problem in finding the charge enclosed by a Gaussian surface. To find the charge enclosed, you will have to integrate the infinitesimal charge of an infinitesimally thin ring.

Let's choose an infinitesimally thin ring of radius $r$ and charge density $\rho$. The infinitesimal volume of this ring is $\mathrm dV=4\pi r^2 \mathrm dr$ (surface area of the ring $\times$ thickness of the ring). Now you can integrate $\rho\mathrm dV$ to find the total charge.